# Такт процессора vs цикл процессора

Tags: информатика

В последнее время в интернете мне всё чаще встречается словосочетание "цикл процессора" или "процессорный цикл" в значении "такт". Поводом к написанию этого вопроса стала [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/309796/) на известном IT-ресурсе, которая не является переводом (изначально написана на русском), и в которой автор упорно использует слово "цикл" для обозначения такта. Очевидно, что слово "цикл" в этом значении пришло из английского языка, где такты процессора называются CPU cycles или clock cycles.

Насколько правильно использовать слово "цикл" в таком значении? По моему мнению, это слово и без того перегружено в "компьютерном" контексте, а в таком значении оно выглядит как плохой перевод.

Comment: Не написана она изначально на русском ([Optimizing Program Performance](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/2e/ch5-preview.pdf) - в статье даже честная отсылка есть), поэтому, видимо, и "циклы".

Comment: @jwalker Но статья явно не является переводом, на что и отсылк намекает: "На написание этой статьи меня вдохновила пятая глава из книги...". Больше похоже на вольный пересказ своими словами, поэтому странно видеть в ней слово, похожее на "ложного друга переводчика".

Comment: Всю статью я не проверял, но цельнотянутые куски присутствуют.

Comment: I wonder if it belongs to this site. Too specific.

Comment: Anyway,  if it is here, its essence should be translated for everyone to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Не думаю, что вопрос в это комьюнити, но ощущение верное. *Вообще-то*, правильно "такт", а "цикл" - ненужная калька с английского. То же самое относится, например, к разрядности: правильная терминология "32-разрядный" (а не "32-битный") процессор.

Но, как всегда в таких случаях, сколь бы ни было неграмотным слово, если оно начинает массово использоваться, оно постепенно закрепляется. Так произошло, например, со словом "файервол": мало кто сейчас упорствует с правильным "брандмауэр". Компьютерные термины особенно подвержены этому явлению, поскольку большинство компьютерщиков в той или иной мере двуязычны, и переключаться на другую терминологию утомительно.

Comment: А разве брандмауэр (калька с немецкого) действительно правильней, чем файервол (калька с английского)?

Comment: @Roux, только по причине более раннего (и устоявшегося) заимствования.

Comment: @Roux Не калька, а транскрипция.

Comment: Я не уверен, что брандмауэр - правильное. Брандмауэр - это стенка такая кирпичная в русском языке, а софтина - файрвол. Прелесть заимствований зачастую как раз в устранении неоднозначных слов.

Comment: @alamar, вы, видимо, просто не застали то время, когда это слово использовалось в IT. В прямом смысле оба слова, действительно, идентичны (в своих языках) и означают пожарозащитную стену, а в IT используются в переносном смысле. В русском в данном случае произошло разделение, и я согласен, зачастую это удобно. Но так происходит не всегда, и исходный вопрос со словом "цикл" как раз показывает обратный процесс с перегружением смысла.

Comment: А есть ли сейчас авторитетные терминологические словари?

Comment: @Zeus, нет, я застал. С циклом сложнее, потому что в английском есть loop, поэтому cycle они могут без перегрузки использовать для тактов.